# IPv6 Network is unreachable (os error 101)

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, ipv6, ipv4

Trying to create tcp socket connection between via an Ipv6 address, I get Network is unreachable (os error 101)
As a binding local address is used fe80::850***.
Probably it's because of fe80*** is local ipv6 address generated by OS. Is there a way to provide correct configuration for system to make a call via IPv6?

Comment: Did you properly include the Zone ID for a link-local address?

Answer (score 7):

As it required quite long time to find the main reason of the problem, will try to share the solution/investigation steps:

- To make sure ipv6 is not configured properly just run 'ping6 ipv6.google.com'. It should return some error message like 'connect: Network is unreachable' or just stuck.
- AWS ec2 instances by default are not assigned ipv6 global routable addresses(only ipv4 is assigned). Ipv6 addresses like 'fe80:*' are local routable and can't be used for global requests. To check the list of ip addresses, check eth0 config /sbin/ifconfig. Btw, AWS provides interface to generate global routable ipv6 address for ec2 instance (just check vpc/ec2 console pages - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-migrate-ipv6.html)
- Check security group of ec2 instance and make sure that in route table ipv6 traffic is allowed.Specifically inbound and outbound rules should include '::/0' for ipv6(or one of them based on the need).
- Try 'ping6 ipv6.google.com' again

Comment: "As of version s20150815, the ping6 binary [doesn't exist](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/iputils/ping.8.en#HISTORY) anymore." And what is `eth0 config /sbin/ifconfig`?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:
Your IPv6 connectivity is not setup correctly. This is most probably no configuration problem on your machine, but on the gateway router.

Long answer:
You get a "Network is unreachable" error because your operating system does not know how to reach the destination address. Usually it maintains a table called the *routing table*, where it looks up which network path leads to which ip subnet. It seems that in your case, there are several things missing.

1. Your interface probably has no configured non-link-local (fe80::/64) address
2. There is no routing table entry for the destination address range

In the IPv4 world these missing things are usually resolved by a DHCP server. In the IPv6 world, there are two possible configuration options. Either DHCPv6 is used or the IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration is used. It seems that neither is setup in your network. Note that correctly setting up one of these requires you to have administrative access to your gateway router.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following command to check whether IPv6 is enabled:

```
ip addr
```

- If only an IPv4 address is displayed, IPv6 is disabled. Enable it by referring to this [tutorial](https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/usermanual-ecs/ecs_03_0508.html#section5).
- If a link-local address (starting with fe80) is displayed, IPv6 is enabled but dynamic assignment of IPv6 addresses is not enabled.
- If an IPv6 address other than fe80 is displayed, IPv6 is enabled and an IPv6 address has been assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I only had `If a link-local address (starting with fe80) is displayed`,, after I checked my host panel I found out they don't assign ipv6 to my VPS server

Comment: Yes, @Salem. The same for my Oracle vps.

Comment: Where is the command supposed to be executed? I just tried "ip addr" and "ipaddr" in Windows Command Prompt but it's not a command. However, "ipconfig" is a valid command

Comment: @Stev It ran on Linux. The [tutorial](https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/usermanual-ecs/ecs_03_0508.html#section4:~:text=Click%20Yes.-,Windows,-Server%202012) has details for Windows Server, where you can use ipconfig instead.