# Error accessing raspbian.raspberrypi.org when downloading packages

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt-get

When I try to install anything on my Raspberry Pi 3 I get the following error message, I don't seem to have any trouble connecting to the Internet, as

```
ping google.com
```

and connecting to the pi via ssh work.
Is this a common error or am I missing anything?

```
admin@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo apt-get install motion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfuse2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmariadb3 libmicrohttpd12 libpq5 mariadb-common mysql-common
Suggested packages:
  default-mysql-client postgresql-client
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmariadb3 libmicrohttpd12 libpq5 mariadb-common motion mysql-common
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 947 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,651 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf mysql-common all 5.8+1.0.7 [7,464 B]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf mariadb-common all 1:10.5.15-0+deb11u1 [36.7 kB]
Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libmariadb3 armhf 1:10.5.15-0+deb11u1
  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libmicrohttpd12 armhf 0.9.72-2
  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libpq5 armhf 13.8-0+deb11u1
  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf motion armhf 4.3.2-1
  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Fetched 44.2 kB in 31s (1,438 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.5/libmariadb3_10.5.15-0%2bdeb11u1_armhf.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/libm/libmicrohttpd/libmicrohttpd12_0.9.72-2_armhf.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/postgresql-13/libpq5_13.8-0%2bdeb11u1_armhf.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/motion/motion_4.3.2-1_armhf.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 1):

This link may help. Either the server is dead or ipv6 isn’t working properly.
[IPv6 Network is unreachable (os error 101)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079987/ipv6-network-is-unreachable-os-error-101)
Edit: You can try and add ipv6.disable=1 to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX entries in /etc/default/grub.cfg then run sudo update-grub. This way it will default to ipv4 and work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).